# Pass data to all controller and model in laravel

Tags: laravel-7

I was looking for a way to pass an array to my entire laravel 7 application,
which will be available in controller, views and models.

Currently i can share some variable by extending laravel controller like this

```php
class BaseController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //its just a dummy data object.
    $user = User::all();

    // Sharing is caring
    View::share('user', $user);
  }
}
```

but this works only for views.
Is there a better way to serve data to all controller?
Idea is for every user when the logged in a set of data (like currency and other user spesific settings) will be fetched from database and will be available over all controller.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear, but personally to link information to all users I create functions directly in my model or in my class like a relationship:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{    
   public function currency() {
       return '€';
   }
}
```

So now if I would like to retreive the user currency, I juste need to make

```
$user->currency()
```

Comment: I got your point, but I want a solution by which i can pass array of data to all controller